# Generating report only for particular code in file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, junit4

I want to generate reports for particular java code(newly added particular method).I do not want to generate report for whole project.Is it possible with Jenkins?I am using JUnit for writing test cases.

Answer (score 0):

try integrating with SONAR, and define include / exclude patterns for you case